# Add pipelines environment variables

Tags: aws-copilot

I have a copilot application that contains two pipelines:

```
copilot/pipelines/pipeline_a/
  buildspec.yml
  manifest.yml
copilot/pipelines/pipeline_b/
  manifest.yml
```

Pipeline B manifest references buildspec.yml so it is shared between the two pipelines.

I manually edited the generated pipelines adding environment variables
[image]

Is it possible to include those variables in the copilot configurations files? The most natural place would be in the pipeline manifest.yml but I couldn't find any documentation for that, and nothing I tried was visible within the buildspec.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on [copilot-cli github pages](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/5383).

> To quickly unblock the use case right now you can run copilot pipeline
> override and in your yaml patch file you can specify env vars like
> this
>
> ```
> - op: add
>   path: /Resources/BuildProject/Properties/Environment/EnvironmentVariables/-
>   value:
>     Name: VARIABLE_NAME
>     Value: value_a
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but just adding some context to jerome's answer which took me a second to get to.

- Call `copilot pipeline override --name <pipeline_name>`

I had to update my `copilot-cli` first to get this to work so watch out for that.

This call should create a new file (one I had yet to use) under `/overrides` in your `pipeline` folder. Should be called `cfn.patches.yml`

In there you can add the command lines from Jerome which will set the ENV Vars.

```
# Delete the task role resource
# - op: remove
#   path: /Resources/TaskRole

# Add a service connect alias
# - op: add
#   path: /Resources/Service/Properties/ServiceConnectConfiguration/Services/0/ClientAliases/-
#   value:
#     Port: !Ref TargetPort
#     DnsName: yamlpatchiscool

# Replace the task role in the task definition
# - op: replace
#   path: /Resources/TaskDefinition/Properties/TaskRoleArn
#   value: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyTaskRole
```

This saved me a lot of time each time I deploy a new pipeline so hope it helps!